# Background in Motion Tracking isnt shown when rendered

Tags: rendering, video, tracking

https://i.stack.imgur.com/syegg.jpg

When i render my video, i cant see the movie clip in the background, but in the camera. How can i render the video?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times

Comment: The solution for the last question doesnt work for this one. Now its switched.

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice, add information to the original post instead. The key to understanding why your image is not rendering is in the compositor and how the render layers are set up. Without that information is hard to help you.